# Configure Databricks with MongoDB-Atlas

Tags: databricks, mongodb-atlas

I want to connect mongodb-atlas with databricks, in the spark connector documentation they mentioned give ip address of databricks in the mongodb-atlas IP Whitelist. My question is how to get the IP address from databricks, Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the images if you go to Azure account and go to data bricks, you can see Managed resource group, click on it and check for Public IP address, click on it and can see the Public IP address

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]

Answer (score 1):

Get a single NAT-like public IP or CIDR for all Azure Databricks clusters, which could be configured in a whitelist for any data source.

This is a high-level guide on how to establish connectivity from your Azure Databricks Workspace to your on-premises network. It is based on the hub-and-spoke topology shown in the following diagram, where traffic is routed via a transit virtual network (VNet) to the on-premises network.

This process requires your Azure Databricks workspace to be deployed in your own virtual network (also known as VNet injection).

[image]

Atlas only allows client connections to the cluster from entries in the project’s whitelist. Each entry is either a single IP address or a CIDR-notated range of addresses. For AWS clusters with one or more [VPC Peering connections](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-vpc-peering/#vpc-peering) to the same AWS region, you can specify a Security Group associated with a peered VPC.

For Atlas clusters deployed on [Google Cloud Platform (GCP)](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/google-gcp/#google-gcp) or [Microsoft Azure](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/microsoft-azure/#microsoft-azure), add the IP addresses of your GCP or Azure services to Atlas project IP whitelist to grant those services access to the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

use the code snippet to get the IP of  your databricks cluster

````
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.ipify.org?format=json') as response:
    html=response.read()
    print(html) ```
````

Comment: that will not work 
IP is dynamic